# A substitute for struct hash_desc in kernel

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel

I have to port a kernel module my coworker and I built in the 2.6.38 to the 2.6.18 kernel.  Everything was going well, until we hit this brick wall. One of the compile errors was:

```
variable 'desc' does not have predefined size
```

Doing some looking around I found that it was because it was not defined anywhere due to the fact that it did not exist in this version of the kernel.  The definition is for `struct hash_desc` which is missing in the Linux 2.6.18 src/include directory but is found in `linux/crypto.h` of the Linux 2.6.38 src/include directory.

I've searched the the 2.6.18 source as thoroughly as I could, using `grep -H -R "struct hash_desc" .` being a great help, and I've come to the conclusion that it is not there at least in this form.  Is it possible that it is under some different name or if not, possible to easily reconstruct this struct and it's functionality?

Comment: And you do not have the 2.6.38 kernel sources to check yourself, I assume?

Comment: Why not (just?) port it (`struct hash_desc`) back from the 2.6.38 sources?

Comment: @Olaf: It seems they do have: "*The missing definition is for `struct hash_desc` found in `linux/crypto.h` of the Linux 2.6.38 src/include directory.*".

Comment: @alk: Yes, but my point is to diff the corresponding sources.

Comment: @Olaf: So why didn't you comment this then, but something else .. ;-)

Comment: pertinent link: http://ewg.openfabrics.narkive.com/vUPgYanW/rhel5-backports-and-crypto-functions

Comment: @alk: Well, I should have been more clear, but for me "check" includes all measures, which `diff` is one part of. (The comment itself was meant ironically)

Comment: @Olaf I do have the kernel 2.6.38 sources, I also have the 2.6.18 kernel sources.  I can see the `struct hash_desc` just fine in the 2.6.38 but it is not in the 2.6.18.

Comment: @alk We can not port it, because the system we are building it for does not have both kernels, only 2.6.18.  And they do not want to put 2.6.38 on it.

Comment: @GUIDO I've searched all the files in the `include/Linux` directory in the machine running 2.6.18 and not one of them turned up that file nor the struct

Comment: @alk: Because that way leads directly to ODR violations.